# What is the most efficient way to handle the interpretation of commands/input in a java program?

Tags: java, input

Edit for clarity:

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to:

1. store possible commands (like having some sort of data structure full of valid commands)
2. check the user-entered command against the stored commands and, if they line up, execute the related methods

I'm finding this question difficult to word, so if any clarification is needed, please let me know.

I'm trying to make a command line calendar, and currently it takes in a lot of commands and arguments separated by "|" like so:

> calendar|add|"EventNameString"|"EventDescriptionString"|"EventDate"
>   help
>   calendar|print
>   calendar|remove|"EventNameString"|"EventDate"

I then split the input based on the "|"s. What I'm wondering is what is the best way to interpret successful commands. Currently I am using a bunch of if statements. For example, using the first sample input above, it would check to see if the first argument matches "calendar" and if so, it would check to see if the second command is "add", "print", etc.

I was thinking that there may be some way to store a list of acceptable commands in some sort of data structure and then use the data structure to optimally check if the input matches a valid command (and execute the command if so).

Here is the code for my interpreting of the commands. I can show or explain more if needed:

```
public StatusMessage parseCommand(String command) {
    String[] command_args = command.split("\\|");
    if(command_args.length == 0)
        return noInputFailure;
    if(command_args[0].toLowerCase().equals("help")) {
        System.out.println("USAGE");
        System.out.println("App: calendar");
        System.out.println("");
    }
    else if(command_args[0].toLowerCase().equals("calendar")) {

        String input_arg1 = command_args[1].toLowerCase();
        if(input_arg1.equals("add")) {
            DateFormat date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = (Date)date_format.parse(command_args[4]);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                return dateFormatFailure;
            }
            calendar.addEvent(command_args[2], command_args[3], date);
            return genericSuccess;
        }
        if(input_arg1.equals("print")) {
            calendar.print();
            return genericSuccess;
        }

    }

    return genericFailure;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code for what you are currently doing?  This would make it easier to suggest sensible changes.

Comment: Added some! Let me know if you need more context or anything.

Comment: consider using a switch statement for clearer code

Comment: Yeah, but I'm looking to an alternative to having simply hard coded commands like so. If I can't find an alternative way however, I do agree that I should clean it up by using a switch.

Comment: Looks like question has been closed so I can't post an answer. I would say take a look at the command design pattern, which you can do in any language, including Java.  The Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) is a nice place to start. Imagine storing the command instances in a `Map`, with the command names ("help", "calendar") as keys for selecting the command, and you get the idea of what I would suggest.  Sorry the question got closed.

Comment: A map sounds promising. Do you have any advice for rewording the question? I'm not sure how they want me to clarify.

Comment: Anything with *what is the best way* is going to be closed as **opinion based** and **too broad** and probably a couple of other reasons as well.